# Importing .tflite(model) and .txt(labels) into react native project

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow-lite

I am currently trying to incorporate tensorflowlite into my react native project. I am following this documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tflite-react-native#Image-Classification

I have currently tried this method. I have added the files directly by dragging them into my assets folder.
[image]

```
export default class Statistics extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let tflite = new Tflite();
    tflite.loadModel({
      model: './assets/model.tflite',// required
      labels: './assets/dict.text',  // required
      numThreads: 1,                              // defaults to 1  
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if(err)
        console.log(err);
      else
        console.log(res);
    });
    this.state = {
      imageurl: '',
    }
  }
```

However, I am receiving this error: "null is not an object (evaluating 'TfliteReactNative.loadModel')]"
I think this is because I have incorrectly imported my files. What is the correct way to add the .tflite and .txt files into my react native project. I am using expo with visual studio code.

Comment: How to add a model to iOS App? I tried many ways to add my model to iOS app, but always gets `Null is not an object evaluating (TfliteReactNative.loadModel)` error in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/shaqian/tflite-react-native?categoryPage=47) explains that you place the model as `app/src/main/assets/model.tflite`, but in your code you address them as `models/model.tflite`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to add model to iOS. I am always getting `Null is not an object evaluating (TfliteReactNative.loadModel)` error in iOS.